# Does the client side NIO really matter?

Tags: java, client, nio

As far as I know, NIO can help the server, serve a lot of the requests.  Because NIO does not use one thread per request model.

But the client is the one create the connection to the server, usually there are not so many connections, and the client can handle it completely.

I saw some client libraries use NIO, and I am not so sure about it. So why brother NIO on the client side and is there any performance improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no great reason to use NIO at the client, unless possibly you are writing something like a web crawler that has hundreds or thousands of outbound connections.

There's arguably not much reason to user at the server either. The select() model was designed for the days when the alternative was forking a process. Now we have threads, the whole model is moot IMHO.

Comment: "The select() model was designed for the days when the alternative was forking a process. Now we have threads, the whole model is moot IMHO."  That's a pretty strong statement.  Events offer a different paradigm (which some people find more natural), and the over head of threads, though small individually, becomes too much after a fairly low number.

Comment: @Corbin You say 'a fairly low number', I say'hundreds or thousands'. I don't see any disagreement here.

Comment: By the time you account for scheduling overhead and memory overhead, I think hundreds would be closer.  Threading is a definitely a lot more viable now than it used to be, but I don't think that seeing event driven systems as moot is accurate.  This is to a large extent comparing apples to oranges, but imagine a threaded webserver versus an event driven one (whether `select` or some other mechanism).  Which do you think is going to scale better?

Comment: In terms of scalability, the thread-per-client approach is downright irresponsible. The JVM thread scheduler was not intended to be an I/O readiness notification system and will not perform well for more than a couple dozen clients.

I think if you plan to have your server scale to more than 50-100 clients and performance is critical, NIO is the only option. The fact that it's difficult to use does not excuse the need for proper scalability in servers. The `Selector` implementation on Linux even uses the `epoll` library for amazing performance allowing for 10,000+ clients with relative ease.